# Using JQuery to remove an input and print its value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do the following with JQuery:

See if a text input has a value
If it does, then make it read only or make it hidden and print the value in a div where the input was
If it doesn't have a value, then it behaves as normal.

I've tried using the hide() and read-only JQuery functions but it doesn't seem to be working. I can only refer to the input by its name (I can't edit the original code to add a class)

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do this:

```
$('input').filter(function() {
   return $(this).val().length > 0;
}).attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide().each(function() {
   $(this).closest('div').append(' ' + $(this).val());
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jacobrelkin/Sf92H/)**

Comment: Thaks for the quick reply, but that doesn't seem to work - my html code is:`<form id="your-profile">
<input type="text" value="CG548OP" name="paypal-custom-8"/>
</form>`. The input is still editable...

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/SSW6v/1/ - there is solution